# Validate device's self signed certificate

Tags: c#, certificate, ssl-certificate, self-signed

The scenario is: We have a linux device with a certificate. The device certificate is signed by the intermediate certificate which is signed by the Root certificate so the depth level is 3. There is a service which makes Https calls to the linux device. The service is hosted on a windows workstation and in the CA trust store is installed the public key of the Root certificate which signs the device. The problem is that we cannot figure out a proper way to validate the device certificate on the workstation side.

We tried to validate the certificate by adding the public certificate in the trusted Root certificate authorities for local user on Windows when the HttpWebRequest is created.

```
var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(endpoint);
httpWebRequest.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = CertificateValidationHandler;
```

and the handler is:

```
bool CertificateValidationHandler(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
{
  if (sslPolicyErrors == SslPolicyErrors.None)
  {
   return true;
  }

  //Validate certificate
}
```

The easy way is simple `return true;` in the validation but we would like to have a proper certificate handling.

Comment: Can you tell us what happens when yo do not set the `ServerCertificateValidationCallback `? What would you like to validate? Expiry, That it is not revoked (Certificate Revocation List or Online Responder)? The Issuer?

Comment: Your trust chain consists of the device certificate, the intermediate CA issuing that, and the root CA issuing the intermediate. Your workstation only knows to trust the root CA, and presumably your linux device only presents the device certificate when responding to HTTPS requests. So there clearly a piece missing and the client workstation is not able to establish the trust chain. Your linux device should present (at minimum) the intermediate certificate along with its device-specific cert (if not the full chain).

Comment: @AmitKumarGupta Thank you for your analysis. Based on it we tried to see if indeed the Linux device (server) provides only the leaf and not the intermediate certificate. In the server callback we only see the leaf. However when we tried the same with a Java application - to compare - we did receive a combination of leaf and intermediate. So the linux device is behaving as expected in that case provides the chain. Could it be that this is somehow controlled in the client? Do you perhaps know of a setting on the .NET side to 'control' the server response when it comes to certificates?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the comments. After spending some time trying to figure out how to handle the `ServerCertificateValidationCallback` from `HttpWebRequest` I decided to change the approach and try different http .net implementations. I tested with `System.Net.Http.HttpClient` class and the callback returned the full certificate chain validated properly. Furthermore there is a suggestion in [ms docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest?view=netframework-4.8) to not use `HttpWebRequest` for new development. Usage example:

```
HttpClientHandler httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
httpClientHandler.CertificateCustomValidationCallback = ValidationCallback;
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler))
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After some testing we find out that the problem was with .net core 2.0 for both HttpWebRequest & HttpClient. Update the framework to .net core 2.1 validation worked properly for both. The problem is with the .net core 2.0 how it handles the certificate validation callback. The issue was not fixed because of the HttpClient but because we update the version to 2.1. Furthermore, the validation callbacks retrieves the certificate chain fine  with .net framework 4.6.1